# I need to make a standalone service for detecting and executing custom Windows hotkeys

Tags: windows, automation, windows-services, autohotkey

I am attempting to make a macro keyboard that will automatically open some webpages and programs for me. In order to accomplish this, I have made a custom keyboard that is able to input keystrokes for me.

I would like to use a key combination like ctrl + a + b + c to activate my macros so that it does not interfere with the macros I already have on my keyboard. I have attempted to use Auto Hotkey for this purpose, but it does not accept multiple keys like I want.

I, therefore, believe that I will be forced to code my own hotkey manager. Here are the features That I want to be included in my hotkey manager:

- Multiple key activation. example: ctrl + a + b + c
- Ability to open webpages.
- Ability to run programs.
- preferably a single program, so that it can be used on multiple computers easily.

Is a project like this possible for an intermediate programmer?

I am currently experimenting with C# and Windows services, but I am unable to figure out how to listen for keystrokes. I am not married to C#. I can change languages as needed.

Any advice you would give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AutoHotKey seems like a good option.

Comment: *"I have attempted to use Auto Hotkey for this purpose, but it does not accept multiple keys like I want."* I'd like to say that you will be able to do this and you probably just didn't know how to. If you post a more specific problem/what you tried to do, I can see about fixing up the AHK code. Everything you listed is doable with AHK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) instead of a multi-key [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

A hotstring is a *sequence* of keystrokes.

You can define hotstrings like this

```
::btw::by the way
```

Typing "btw" and then a <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> or any word terminator, will expand "btw" to "by the way"

[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) can also be used to open webpages, run programs etc.